# Make file error *** missing separator upon making intel ethernet driver

Tags: drivers, make, ethernet, intel

Hi all Thanks for reading

I recently installed Ubuntu MATE 16.0.4 and trying to install Intel I219-V ethernet driver which could be found https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/82186/Intel-Ethernet-Connection-I219-V.

I was following the readme file until out of no where I cannot make with the Makefile inside and gets an error saying Makefile:3: *** missing separator. Stop.

I tried changing spaces to tabs and what not but i cannot seem to figure out what is actually wrong with it with my short spectrum of knowledge in linux. Can anyone help me? below is the make file and it is coming from line 3 for now.

```
#$FreeBSD$

.include <bsd.own.mk>

.PATH:  ${.CURDIR}

KMOD    = if_em
SRCS    = device_if.h bus_if.h pci_if.h
SRCS    += $(CORE_SRC) $(COMMON_SHARED) $(LEGACY_SHARED) $(PCIE_SHARED)
CORE_SRC = if_em.c if_lem.c e1000_osdep.c em_compat.c
# Shared
COMMON_SHARED = e1000_api.c e1000_phy.c e1000_nvm.c e1000_mac.c e1000_manage.c
PCIE_SHARED = e1000_80003es2lan.c e1000_ich8lan.c e1000_82571.c
LEGACY_SHARED = e1000_82540.c e1000_82542.c e1000_82541.c e1000_82543.c

# These flags are only used when in a standalone tarball build
CFLAGS  += -DINET -DINET6 -DEM_STANDALONE_BUILD

# Uncomment this to disable Fast interrupt handling.
#CFLAGS  += -DEM_LEGACY_IRQ

# DEVICE_POLLING for a non-interrupt-driven method
#CFLAGS  += -DDEVICE_POLLING

# Uncomment this to enable the stack multiqueue routines
# with this driver you do not get multiple tx queues,
# but it does provide input queuing. Testing has shown
# some stability issues so its off by default.
# NOTE: it has been found that UDP intensive traffic
#       actually does better with the old stack interface
#       and so it seems better to have this off by default.
#       however it works fine, and some workloads may benefit
#       having it on.
#CFLAGS  += -DEM_MULTIQUEUE

clean:
    rm -f opt_bdg.h device_if.h bus_if.h pci_if.h setdef*
    rm -f *.o *.kld *.ko
    rm -f @ machine export_syms x86
    rm -f ${CLEANFILES}

.include <bsd.kmod.mk>
```

Comment: You're trying to compile a FreeBSD driver on Linux.

Comment: Yeah I just downloaded under the linux tab and blindly trusted Intel Thanks for catching.

Answer (score 1):

Despite what the Intel web site states in the “OS” column, the driver you downloaded is a FreeBSD driver (as indicated by its name on the web site, “Intel® Network Adapter Gigabit Base Driver for FreeBSD”). It won’t work on Linux.

On Linux, you shouldn’t need to install anything; the i219 chipset is supported by the `e1000e` driver in the kernel, since at least version 4.1.

Comment: awe thanks I got confused as the Intel page had a tab for linux drivers and I was just blindly believing that it was going to be a driver for linux.

Answer (score 1):

This is a FreeBSD driver and a BSD Makefile.

GNU `make` will not understand the Makefile, and the driver will not be able to compile on your Ubuntu system (even if you rewrote the Makefile) since drivers by necessity are heavily dependent on the kernel they were written for.

Download a Linux version of the driver.

Tangentally related: [Is it possible to copy a driver from Windows to Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334093/is-it-possible-to-copy-a-driver-from-windows-to-linux)